# redirecting to a page after successful login in spring through ajax

Tags: grails, spring-security

Am a newbie to Grails. I am using Grails 3.3.2 and am trying to implement security plugin in my app. How do I redirect to a certain page after a successful login.

Comment: `location.href = new-location-here`

Comment: Are you using spring security plugin?

Comment: Yes am using the security plug-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Grails controller you will have the if check of successful login, inside that condition you can write the redirect statement as below,

```
    redirect(controller: 'YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME', action:'YOUR_GSP_PAGE_NAME')
```

If you want to redirect page with specific path then use following syntax,

```
redirect(uri: "PATH_TO_YOUR_PAGE")
```

See more examples here [Grails redirect examples](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html)

Comment: Yes am using the security plug in. Where do I place the above line of code?

Comment: Yes, try above line inside your check

Comment: @FrancisTing Is it woked?

Comment: Am still having a bit of a problem @Nitlin Dhomse. Which controller should I place your code since I have several including the login and the logout controllers( which are only accessible from the browser and not the IDEcontroller which were auto-generated for me). I used the s2-quickstart command

Comment: The controller in which   your gsp file is declared  (the page you want to redirect)

Comment: I edited my answer if you don't have gsp file, may be .html file, you can redirect to html or any file.